# Regex to match and remove comma (,) inside a tag

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

```
<IndustryCapab,ilityDescr>RES</IndustryCapabilityDescr><IndustryS,pecialtyDescr>RES-Cross Industry</IndustrySpecialt,yDescr>
```

Desired result:

```
</CapabilityDescr><IndustryCapabilityDescr>RES</IndustryCapabilityDescr><IndustrySpecialtyDescr>RES-Cross Industry</IndustrySpecialtyDescr>
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  What research have you done into the kind of regex that might help you here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\,(?=[^<>]*>)", "");
```

**Detail** :

`\,` # Match a Comma

`(?=`     # only if the following regex can be matched at the current position:

`[^<>]*` #  - zero or more characters except < or >

> ```
>  #  - followed by a >
> ```

`)`       # End of lookahead assertion

Comment: comma is not a metacharacter, so you can easily write `,`

Answer (score 1):

try this out (in C#)

```
var s = "<IndustryCapab,ilityDescr>RES</IndustryCapabilityDescr><IndustryS,pecialtyDescr>RES-Cross Industry</IndustrySpecialt,yDescr>";
var sNew = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=</?\w+),(?=\w+>)","");
```

We're using positive lookahead and lookbehind to sort out all words and tags around and look only for the comma.